# IIS Script to disable directory browse for multiple applications

Tags: powershell, iis

This script below works wonderfully for one application/site if I know the hardcoded name. However, I am looking for a way to accomplish what this script does but for all sites under Default Website. Below is an example as well as shown in IIS. Any help is appreciated.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE/TESTAPPLICATION2' -filter "system.webServer/directoryBrowse" -name "enabled" -value "False"
```

I am needed everything that is in bold underneath default website to be have directory browsing turned off. This would be simple if it was just one server, but we are looking at 50+ servers and a script would save a lot of time. Once again the application names are not hardcoded and are all different. I am just trying to figure out a way to disable the feature multiple sites/applications at a time.

- Default Site

Test Application 1

Test Application 2

Test Application 3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
$siteName = "Default Web Site"
$site = Get-IISSite -Name $siteName
$apps = $site.Applications
ForEach ($app In $apps) {
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$site$($app.Path)" -Filter "system.webServer/directoryBrowse" -Name "enabled" -Value "False"
}
```

What the script does:

1. Get the site.
2. Get the site's apps.
3. Loop through each app and set the property you want.

If you want an one-liner, here it is:

```
$siteName = "Default Web Site"
(Get-IISSite -Name $siteName).Applications.foreach({Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$site$($_.Path)" -Filter "system.webServer/directoryBrowse" -Name "enabled" -Value "False"})
```

Comment: This is perfect. Ze Claudio, you are a gem. Thank you very much. I am still very new to all of this and doing my best. Your work is much appreciated.

Comment: Any way I could tie this in properly to where it could list out the site/or tell me if it's enabled? 

Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/directoryBrowse -name enabled

Comment: You just have to change the code inside the ForEach loop to do what you want. In this case, change to `Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$site$($app.Path)" -Filter "system.webServer/directoryBrowse" -Name "enabled"`. You'd probably have to print the app name to make it more useful. But it's clear that you don't know much PowerShell, or even programming, cause this is a really simple thing to do. Consider learning at least PowerShell basic programming before trying to use it.

Comment: Claudio thanks again, of course I do not know much I am not a developer like yourself. As stated I am very new to this, but figured asking a question wouldn't hurt.

Comment: It doesn't hurt me, but it can hurt you if you trust anything someone says you should execute in your server without knowing exactly what you're doing. But it kinda hurts when you take your time to answer a question and the person who made it doesn't accept it as correct in StackOverflow... ;)